# Find all values of $x$ such that $\sin(2x) = \sin(x)$ and $x \in [0, 2\pi]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The answers are $0, \frac{\pi}{3}, \pi, \frac{5\pi}{3}$ and $2\pi$.  I found $\frac{\pi}{3}$ and $\frac{5\pi}{3}$ algebraically, I overlooked $0$ and $2\pi$, but understood once I looked at the answer, but I'm missing how I could have found $\pi$.  Here's what I did.

I noticed that $\sin(2x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x)$, so we can multiply both sides by $\frac{1}{\sin(x)}$ and we eventually get $\cos(x) = \frac12$, which set me looking for the solutions of this last equation, but the $\cos(\pi) = -1$ which is not $\frac12$, so I would have concluded that $\pi$ does not solve the original problem.

I must be losing information with this algebra, but I can't spot what step is wrong.  I believe I'm making a mistake of the sort that we do with square roots.  For instance, if $x^2 = 4$, I could incorrectly conclude that $x = 2$ and overlook that $x = -2$ also works.

So my question is more than how to solve this particular problem.  My question is what should I look out for when I replace one trigonometric equation for another.  (If I'm on the right track here, that is.)  Thank you.

**Reference**. This is problem 8 in Stewart's Calculus 6th edition, tests of algebra D.  (The verification tests so we know what we'll need in reading the book.)

Comment: To divide by $\sin x$ you need that $\sin x \ne 0$. So at that point you need to consider the cases: 1. $\sin x = 0$, which leads to $x = 0, \pi, 2\pi$ and  2. $\sin x \ne 0$ and which  leads to $\cos x = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Note that $$\sin(2x)=\sin(x)\implies \sin(x)(2\cos(x)-1)=0$$So, either $\sin(x)=0$ or $2\cos(x)-1=0$.  Can you finish now?

Comment: Students make mistakes like yours all the time. In order to divide by $\sin x$, you must ensure that $\sin x\neq 0$, which may discard a valid solution.

Comment: ^ Consider $x^2=x$, in the absence of care, a student may divide both sides by $x$ and end up with $x=1$. While $x=1$ is a valid solution, $x=0$ is also a valid solution. The correct way is $x^2-x=0 \implies x(x-1)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You lose information when you divide by $\sin x$.  Keep in mind that division by $\sin x$ is only permissible when you know that $\sin x \neq 0$.  Rather than dividing, you should factor.

\begin{align*}
\sin(2x) & = \sin x\\
2\sin x\cos x & = \sin x\\
2\sin x\cos x - \sin x & = 0\\
\sin x(2\cos x - 1) & = 0
\end{align*}
Since a product is equal to zero if and only if one of its factors is equal to zero, we obtain
\begin{align*}
\sin x & = 0 & \text{or} & & 2\cos x - 1 & = 0\\
x & = 0, \pi, 2\pi & & & 2\cos x & = 1\\
  & & & & \cos x & = \frac{1}{2}\\
  & & & & x & = \frac{\pi}{3}, \frac{5\pi}{3}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you!  That's a very neat exposition.

Answer (score 2):

$\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)=\sin(x)$

$\implies \sin(x)=0$ or $\cos(x)=\frac12$

$\implies x \in \{0, \frac{\pi}{3}, \pi, \frac{5\pi}{3}, 2\pi \}$

You did almost the same thing except you forgot to consider the fact that $\sin(x)$ can be $0$ as well and in that case you cannot cancel it.

A similar problem comes when you solve $x^2=2x$, in this case also, $x$ can be both $0$ and $2$.

So, instead of doing this you can consider$x^2=2x$ as $(x-2)x=0$, then one of the factors on the RHS must be 0 which implies $x$ can be $2$ or $0$.

Similarly, $2\sin(x)\cos(x)=\sin(x) \implies \sin(x)(\cos(x)-\frac12)=0$ and then you can proceed.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: $\frac{3\pi}{3}$?

Comment: Sorry, it should be $\frac{5\pi}{3}$

Comment: That's a pretty nice and simple answer!  But it would be even nicer if you were to replace some math symbolism in the beginning of the answer with actual words.  These words could sort of tell the reader what you're about to do --- so that the reader's eyes can expect to find in the calculations that are about to appear.

Answer (score 2):

You can multiply both sides of an equation by any *nonzero* number and you don't lose information.

But you're multiplying both sides by $1/\sin x$ without taking into account that this might be undefined, which it is when $\sin x=0$.

So you *can* remove the common factor $\sin x$ after having noted that $\sin x=0$ *is* a solution of the equation.

It's like when you have $x^2=x$. You cannot multiply by $1/x$, unless you first note that $x=0$ is a solution.

It's much better to rewrite this equation as $x^2-x=0$, factorize $x(x-1)=0$ and conclude that either $x=0$ or $x=1$.

---

Now let's see some ways that can be used to solve the equation

You should know that
$$
\sin\alpha=\sin\beta
$$
if and only if

- $\alpha$ and $\beta$ differ by an integral multiple of $2\pi$, or
- $\alpha+\beta$ differs from $\pi$ by an integral multiple of $2\pi$.

Thus your equation becomes

- $2x=x+2k\pi$, or
- $2x+x=\pi+2k\pi$

In the first case we find $x=2k\pi$, accounting for the solutions $x=0$ or $x=2\pi$ in the specified interval.

In the second case we find $x=\pi/3+2k\pi/3$, accounting for the solutions
$$
x=\dfrac{\pi}{3},\quad x=\pi,\quad x=\dfrac{5\pi}{3}
$$
in the specified interval. Putting things together, we find
$$
0,\quad \dfrac{\pi}{3},\quad \pi,\quad \dfrac{5\pi}{3},\quad 2\pi
$$

In a different way, rewrite the equation as
$$
\sin x(2\cos x-1)=0
$$
and solve separately $\sin x=0$ and $\cos x=1/2$.

In the particular case this is perhaps easier. But what if you had $\sin 7x=\sin5x$?

Another way, recall the sum-to-product formula
$$
\sin\alpha-\sin\beta=2\cos\dfrac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\sin\dfrac{\alpha-\beta}{2}
$$
(I always go and look up for them). In your case you get
$$
2\cos\dfrac{3x}{2}\sin\dfrac{x}{2}=0
$$
and you solve separately $\cos(3x/2)=0$ and $\sin(x/2)=0$. The former yields $3x/2=\pi/2+k\pi$, so $x=\pi/3+2k\pi/3$; the latter yields $x/2=k\pi$, so $x=2k\pi$ and you go as before to identify those that belong to $[0,2\pi]$.

Take your pick.

Comment: The answer provided here is unnecessarily complex. :)

Comment: @CroCo I might add a complex (number based) one. 

Comment: @egreg, you're the TeX master!  Thanks for replying!  I liked your answer very much.  I'm still processing all the awesome feedback I find here.  I'm pretty sure you could really come up with a complex-number-based one!  But, please, don't. :-)

Comment: @CroCo has a point, of course.  I'm choosing Taussig's answer because it might actually help further readers.  But I do appreciate your input quite a lot because it's nice to study a problem we (now) know how to solve --- seeing other ways to look at it and so on.

Comment: I won't be surprised. Such things are notoriously attributed to mathematicians. :)